# Passing function and operator calls in object

Tags: c++, c++11, immutability

I am wanting to make a class which allows me to lock an object from being modified.  It would essentially be a template with a boolean specifying the lock state.  Since it is a template, I won't know all the methods that can be called on the internal object, so I need a method to pass calls through...

```
template<class T>
class const_lock
{
  public:
  const_lock() : my_lock(false) {}
  void set_const_lock(bool state) {my_lock = state;}

  // HOW TO IMPLEMENT SOMETHING LIKE THESE????
  //
  template<typename...Args >
  auto operatorANY_OPERATOR (Args...args)
 {
    if(my_lock != false)
       throw std::exception("Objected locked to modification");
    return my_value.ANY_OPERATOR(args);
 }

  template<typename...Args >
  auto operatorANY_CONST_OPERATOR (Args...args) const
 {
    return my_value.ANY_CONST_OPERATOR(args);
 }

  template<typename...Args >
  auto ANY_METHOD(Args...args)
 {
    if(my_lock != false)
       throw std::exception("Objected locked to modification");
    return my_value.ANY_METHOD(args);
 }

  template<typename...Args >
  auto ANY_CONST_METHOD(Args...args) const
 {
    return my_value.ANY_CONST_METHOD(args);
 }

  private:
    bool my_lock;
    T my_value;
}

int main()
{
  const_lock<std::vector<int>> v;
  v.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(7);
  v.set_const_lock(true);
  v.push_back(9); // fails compilation
  std::cout << v.at(1) << std::endl; // ok
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit: changed static assert to throw and exception

Comment: Will an object's lock state ever change at runtime? If not, it doesn't make sense to do a `static_assert` of lock state.

Comment: Possibly, I think it would be nice to allow the user to explicitly set and unset the lock.

Comment: Also, I am not 100% on the use of static assert.  I was using it more as a way to let the programmer catch an instance where they are trying to modify the locked object

Comment: What is the use case for this? I cannot see a good use case for this except some kind of bug checking....

Comment: I want to create load a large amount of data into a structure.  After loading/processing data, I want to get pointers to certain elements so that I do not have to query them each time I want access.  It would be nice to have a way to ensure that I do not do anything that will mess with the data in terms of shuffling or moving to a new memory space which would invalidate my pointers.

Comment: This seems like a problem that could be largely solved by judicious use of const references.

Comment: That actually would work quite nicely I think.  But, I just googled it and unfortunately it seems like the C++ standard doesn't allow arrays of references :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic wrapper class that you can forward the function to using a lambda that captures a reference to the internal member.  In this example I am just using an if statement to check if it is "locked" and if it is then we just modify a copy.

```
template<class T>
class const_lock
{
private:
    bool my_lock;
    mutable T my_value;
public:
    const_lock() : my_lock(false) {}
    void set_const_lock() { my_lock = true; }


    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(my_value))
    {
        if (my_lock)
        {
            T temp{my_value};  // make a copy
            return f(temp);
        }
        else 
            return f(my_value); // modify wrraped value
    }
};

int main()
{
    const_lock<std::string> cl;
    cl([](std::string& s) {
        s = "foobar";
    });
    cl([](std::string& s) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    });
    cl.set_const_lock();
    cl([](std::string& s) {
        s = "we should still be foobar";
    });
    cl([](std::string& s) {
        std::cout << s;
    });
}
```

Comment: This would give me a proper lock, but would I also have access to all std::string methods.  For instance, would it be possible to call the std::string methods size(),empty(), etc.. on cl? cl([]std::string& s{s.size()}) (if it works) seems very verbose.  I'm looking to be able to do cl.size(), cl.empty() and somehow pass those calls onto const_lock::my_value.

Comment: There was a problem with my code.  I have updated the code and here is an example of how to get the size: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/678cef50bd847613

Comment: I know the syntax is somewhat verbose but it is the only way I know to wrap every function of any type.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for addressing the actual question :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do looks rather difficult, but more importantly is over-complicated and unnecessary for what you're trying to do.

Essentially what you're trying to do (correct me if I'm wrong) is create a compile time check of whether you are supposed to able to modify an object at a given time. However, c++ already has a built in way of doing this. Simply declare or pass your object as const or const&, and the compiler will not allow you to modify non-mutable parts of the object. When you want to be able to modify it pass it without const. You can even cast it from const& to regular & when you want to go from code where you can't modify it directly to code where you can, though I don't recommend it.

edit: just saw a comment on the question about no reference arrays. Don't worry about that! The standard library has support for reference wrappers which allow you to essentially store references in arrays or anywhere else.

Comment: The more fundamental problem is that his function call `set_const_lock` could be called in dynamically reached code that is way past static analysis- for trivial example, `if (rand()) v.set_const_lock()`.

Comment: @Puppy Doesn't this lead to the possibility of dynamic errors? I would suggest reorganizing the code so that a given function only procceces either locked or unlocked objects. Then just const& is good enough.

Comment: Yes, of course it does lead to that possibility. That's why a compiler check is unimplementable. The `const` version drops this ability (and rightly so I think; but it's not even remotely the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unimplementable. A trivial modification of your source code shows why this won't work.

```
int main()
{
  const_lock<std::vector<int>> v;
  v.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(7);
  if (rand() % 2)
      v.set_const_lock(true);
  v.push_back(9); // fails compilation
  std::cout << v.at(1) << std::endl; // ok
}
```

You need to completely rethink your approach.

Comment: So, I do not claim my method works at all, the code snippet is just an attempt at illustrating the behavior I am trying to achieve.  I am looking for some guidance as to a) whether it is possible to implement what I want. and b) how to implement it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example illustrating what I would be trying to protect against

```
  class Node
  {
    public:
      Node(int id) : my_id(id) {}
      // . . . 
      int id() {return my_id;}

    private:
      int my_id;
      // . . .
  };

  class Grid
  {
    public:
      Grid() {}
      // . . . 

      void associate(Node* n) { my_nodes.push_back(n); }

    private:
      // . . .
      std::vector<Node*> my_nodes;
  };

  Node* find(std::vector<Node>& Nodes, int ID)
  {
    for(auto i=Nodes.begin(); i!=Nodes.end(); ++i)
    {
      if (i->id() == ID)
      {
        return &*i;
      }
    }
  }

  main()
  {
    std::vector<Node> Nodes;
    // fill Nodes with data


    Grid Array;
    Array.associate( find(Nodes,14325) );
    Array.associate( find(Nodes,51384) );
    Array.associate( find(Nodes,321684) );

    // . . .
    Nodes.push_back(Node(21616)); // this can invalidate my pointers in Array

  }
```

If I was able to make my Nodes vairable be

```
 const_lock<std::vector<Node>> Nodes;
```

then call

```
 Nodes.set_const_lock(true);
```

after populating the data, I wouldn't need to worry about my pointers in Array getting messed up.

Comment: Just as an FYI that is why you should not hold on to pointer to or iterator to elements in a dynamic container.  If you have to store them then store the index as the index will never change unless you are adding/removing from the middle.

Comment: Agreed.  I am currently implementing a lookup each time.  I am hoping to improve performance by not having to do the lookup by index/key if I can come up with a method to guarantee things will not get changed (I know my above example has a poor search algorithm).